# Table's expirationTime is not visible in web interface

Tags: google-bigquery

I wonder why BQ doesn't display expirationTime in UI:
[image: Table info]

*Expiration date: 30th April* - not displayed

For this case it's rather important to be aware when the table is going be self-removed.

Is there any chance this property info can be added to the web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web UI now includes the expiration time field as part of the table info.

Comment: And I see you fixed table size info for streamed data too. Thanks! How can I subscribe to your releases?

Answer (score 0):

I agree this makes sense to add. Internal feature request bug filed. You can also add a feature request at the bigquery public issue tracker here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list